# How to receive data from the same UDP port in different threads in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, udp

When I  try to do the following thing

```erlang
init() ->
    case gen_udp:open(10000, [binary, {active, false}]) of
        {ok, Socket} ->
            startListen(5, Socket);
    end.

startListen(0, Socket) ->
    Socket;
startListen(N, Socket) ->
    Pid = spawn_link(fun() -> listen(Socket) end),
    startListen(N-1, Socket).

listen(Socket)->
    receive
        {udp, Socket, Host, Port, Data} ->
            ...
    end.
```

It shows that it can not receive from any thread. Did I do something wrongly, or in fact it is not possible in erlang?

Answer (score 2):

You did something wrong. When the socket is not an active socket, your 5 processes must explicitly call `gen_udp:recv/2,3` yourself in this scenario, but I am not entirely sure that will work. I guess you will get a `{error, not_owner}` back.

Another approach which will work is to have the original process grab the packets and then forward them to your workers one at a time as a normal message. This will work, but you need to alter your code a bit.

For background information look at the concept of an owner or controlling process. Each port/socket has one and if the owner crashes, the socket is also closed.